# Google Calendar event list is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am testing Google Calendar Api's `event list` function on the test bed site. The response is not listing event as per the `timeMin` and `timeMax` values. Here are two cases. In both cases I should get a response with an event scheduled between 9:30 to 9:45. But it doesn't appear on the first case (time range: 9:00 to 10:00) but it appears on the second case (time range: 9:00 to 15:00). This didn't work until extended the time range to 15:00. Why is the api acting weirdly?

`Case 1:`

`timeMin: 2015-11-06T09:00:00Z`

`timeMax: 2015-11-06T10:00:00Z`

My Request: 
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/MY_EMAIL%40gmail.com/events?timeMax=2015-11-06T10%3A00%3A00Z&timeMin=2015-11-06T09%3A00%3A00Z&fields=description%2Citems(attendees%2Cdescription%2Cend%2Cid%2Cstart%2Csummary)%2Csummary%2CtimeZone&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Response:

```
{
   "summary": "some summary",
   "timeZone": "America/New_York",
   "items": [
   ]
}
```

`Case 2:`

`timeMin: 2015-11-06T09:00:00Z`

`timeMax: 2015-11-06T15:00:00Z`

My Request: 
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/MY_EMAIL%40gmail.com/events?timeMax=2015-11-06T15%3A00%3A00Z&timeMin=2015-11-06T09%3A00%3A00Z&fields=description%2Citems(attendees%2Cdescription%2Cend%2Cid%2Cstart%2Csummary)%2Csummary%2CtimeZone&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Response:

```
{
 "summary": "Some summary",
 "timeZone": "America/New_York",
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "u7tt4icrbfe76tso8qt11oa5gg",
   "summary": "Event summary",
   "description": "Event description",
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2015-11-06T09:30:00-05:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Indiana/Indianapolis"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2015-11-06T09:45:00-05:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Indiana/Indianapolis"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These times are UTC (from your interval in your first request):

```
timeMin: 2015-11-06T09:00:00Z
timeMax: 2015-11-06T10:00:00Z
```

These times are offset: `-05:00` (from the results in your second request):

```
"dateTime": "2015-11-06T09:30:00-05:00"
"dateTime": "2015-11-06T09:45:00-05:00"
```

Your first time interval doesn't include those times due to the offset.

**Update**

@jaykumarark and I chatted about this and it appears to me that he's not missing anything - in order to use this API you have to provide an RFC3339 compliant date stamp including time zone (Z or offset from UTC) so you can't get the server to do the timezone offset calculation for you.

Comment: But it is supposed to use the calendar's default time zone if I didn't specify one myself right? Or rather how can I query it in the right way?

Comment: I believe by adding the 'Z' you are in fact specifying a timezone. Z == Zulu Time == UTC. Try omitting the 'Z'.

Comment: 'Must be an RFC3339 timestamp with mandatory time zone offset, e.g., 2011-06-03T10:00:00-07:00, 2011-06-03T10:00:00Z.' as present in the api documentation. If i specify one without 'Z' it shows an error.

Comment: I guess that's it then - since a time zone offset is required, you'll have to figure out the appropriate one to use - `Z` should be the same as an offset of `00:00`.

Comment: It's not a very good solution though. Because currently daylight saving ends, so time difference is -5:00. In march it would be -4:00. It is kinda ridiculous that the api doesn't handle this well.

Comment: I agree with you - it should allow you to specify no time zone and use your default or current setting. Can you point me to the docs you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94362/discussion-between-davejagoda-and-jaykumarark).